# In Rails, how to retrieve nested object title in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, I'm using `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem to autocomplete the username owner on a `photos#edit` form. I currently have this code

```
= f.autocomplete_field :user_id, autocomplete_user_username_photos_path
```

Which is autocompleting fine but the default value is `2` (which is the current user_id) and when I try to save the object it will try to send the username instead of the id of that username.

Is there an easy way to display in the field the username instead of the id since the relationship is already done and convert to id when is save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display something and send another info with *rails3-jquery-autocomplete* as far as I know. The last time I tried, I ended up doing my own ajax autocomplete.

But, you can keep thing as they are and simply get the user by his username before you save the photo. It will cost you an additional database request, but it does the trick.

In your controller:

```
@photo.user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first # not sure if you need .first here
@photo.save
```

Comment: Can you elavorate an example of that?